# Theoretical explanation behind alpha particle emission

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity

I have started studying radioactive decay.

When I studied alpha-particle emission from an unstable nucleus I wondered why should there be emission of helium nucleus only(alpha particle) and why not lithium nucleus or of any other element.

Is there any explanation as to why emission of helium nucleus is favourable and quite common?

Comment: @dmckee  I agree, it is a duplicate. I should have searched before answering.

Answer (score 2):

The alpha-particle (Helium nucleus) is much more tightly bound (see the figure below) than any other nearby nucleus making it much more favorable energetically for unstable nuclei to decay via alpha emission.  The reason for this tight binding is that both the neutrons and protons in an alpha-particle are in closed s shells making it the first so called doubly magic nucleus.[image: Binding Energy per Nucleon]  The alpha-particle is also a spin 0 system and thus any unstable nucleus that emits an alpha need not change its spin (further enhancing the decay probability via the alpha emission channel).

Comment: Could you explain a bit more precisely this sentence:"The alpha-particle (Helium nucleus) is much more tightly bound that any other nearby nucleus making it much more favorable energetically for unstable nucleus to decay via alpha emission."

Answer (score 0):

All system go towards lowering the total energy. If alpha particle is released the total energy of the resulting system alpha plus residual nucleus ( at infininte separation) would be much lower than other emissions. Its actually a trade off between energy and various selection rules.

Comment: Could you provide any reference to justify your statement: If alpha particle is released the total energy of the resulting system alpha plus residual nucleus ( at infininte separation) would be much lower than other emissions"

Comment: You need table of masses.Consider alpha emitssion from U238. Energy released E1= Mass U238 - (Mass 90 Th234 + Alpha ) Next take the same nucleus emitting two deutrons to reach 90Th234. E2= Mass U238-(Mass 90Th234 + 2 X Mass of deutron). E1 > E2